# Android Animation : Translate Bottom Left to Middle of the Screen

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation

[image]I want to design a layout in which animation like image below.Its not straight from bottom left to middle its should be circular way.Five images should come from left bottom one by one.
I already done the code but its actually not working what i want, I just want to know the what i have to put in the Anim folder(animation resource file)

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="200%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answer is useful of this question but you have to set five anim as you mentioned.

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.first_anim);
        yourView.setAnimation(anim);

Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.two_anim);
    yourView.setAnimation(anim2);

Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.three_anim);
    yourView.setAnimation(anim3);

Animation anim4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.four_anim);
    yourView.setAnimation(anim4);

Animation anim5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.five_anim);
    yourView.setAnimation(anim5);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this we have to create five `anim` `styles` and have to set all these five circles one by one.

**first_anim.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="-300%"
        android:fromYDelta="1100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**second_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="1200"
    android:fromXDelta="-350%"
    android:fromYDelta="800%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

**third_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromXDelta="-380%"
    android:fromYDelta="800%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

**four_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="1800"
    android:fromXDelta="-500%"
    android:fromYDelta="800%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

**five_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="-600%"
    android:fromYDelta="800%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

And now set your view to Animation class.

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.first_anim);
        yourView.setAnimation(anim);
```